# string output error when using save txt

Tags: python, string, format

I have several lists

```
A = [1.5, 1.8, 1.3, .....]
B = ['galaxy', 'star', 'galaxy', ....]
```

I want something like this:

```
1.5       galaxy
1.8       star
1.3       galaxy
```

So I was trying to use savetxt command as follow:

```
savetxt('out.txt', transpose([A,B]), delimiter='\t', fmt=['%f', '%s'])
```

It gave me error message:

> TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.string_

However if I just have one column in the savetxt:

```
savetxt('out.txt', transpose([B]), fmt=['%s'])
```

Then it works fine. I wonder why this happen when I combine different type of data, and how can I output strings with other floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the elements of list A are some kind of string.
Try:

```
savetxt('out.txt', transpose([A, B]), delimiter='\t', fmt=['%s', '%s'])
```

Comment: That works! but I don't really understand why assigning everything to string solve the issue and still have float as output?

Comment: I should added that I actually import A from other files and did some calculations to convert the numbers, so they should be floats...?

Comment: According to the error message you've posted above, they are strings.